# Is there AJAX progress event in IE and how to use it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, events, progress

I tried all I could think of to at least get to the progress function in IE9 but nothing works. All other browsers get inside of the progress function and write test text without any problems. Hopefully someone can help me. Thank you!

```
     var info = document.getElementById('info');
     var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        } 
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) { 
            try {  
                xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");  
            } 
            catch (e) {  
                try {  
                    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
                } 
                catch (e) {}  
            }  
        }
        xhr.attachEvent("onprogress", function(e) {
            info.innerHTML += "loading...<br />";   
        });

        /*xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            info.innerHTML += "loading...<br />";   
        }, false);*/

        xhr.open("GET", "10_MB_File.txt", true);
        xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Unfortunately there's not the `progress` event in the xhr of <= IE9, but I detect it with this condition: `typeof this.ProgressEvent === 'function'`. Where `this`, is `window`, the global object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onprogress` event is part of the XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec...

- http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#event-handlers

... which is not supported by IE 9 and below. However, IE 10 is supposed to support it...

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673569(v=vs.85).aspx#Enhanced_Event_Support

For more information on which browsers support XHR Level 2, take a look at caniuse.com...

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2

Comment: Thank you. I just never though IE was that outdated... Yes, in Windows8 IE10 showed the progress for me.

Comment: you're welcome! yes... IE is pretty awful. if you're doing cross-domain AJX, beware!!!

Answer (score 2):

IE9 and under do not support onprogress, hence why you can not get it to work.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log('onprogress' in xhr);
```

Comment: why are you creating new object of XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `onreadystatechange` event and display your message. I'm just suggesting it as a workaround.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) {
        // Display a progress message here.
    } else if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200) {
        // Request is finished, do whatever here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In the actual program, bandwidth speedometer, I need to rotate a speed needle based on bytes loaded / seconds passed, so...

Answer (score 0):

Adding to suggestion list, if JQuery is used in your project. It can be achieved by below functions and ofcourse, it needs to be JQuery $.ajax request. Advantage of these client libraries is they have objects instantiated based on browsers. For ex: JQuery takes care of "ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")" or "ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")" based on browser.

```
//displays progress bar
$('#info').ajaxStart(function () {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Yes, in the actual program I use jQuery. But if IE <= 9 doesn't support progress event, I think no library can help here? Or is it actually possible to get progress (bytes loaded) in IE in some way?

Comment: If you call $.ajax/$.get/$.post for AJAX operations, ajaxStart() function which I posted works as progress event to display progress bar. I checked it for IE 6 and it works fine.

Comment: However, it only displays the static content (image/html) as progress bar. If it needs to be real time progress like bytes loaded, other alternatives needs to be searched. In some of the articles I read, one way is to trick the user interface by quickly showing 90% progress and then complete remaining 10% after receiving response from server.