# why Google cloud storage not opening in internet explorer 9 browser

Tags: internet-explorer, google-cloud-storage

Recently i tried to login Google Cloud Storage from IE 9 (Internet Explorer 9) but it shown me Unsupported browser. I had attached screen shot for your reference.

Do i need to configure any of my browser settings or does Google really doesn't allow to login from  IE 9 browser.

[image: UnSupported Browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not work with Google Cloud Storage's web UI.

The web UI relies on a variety of HTML 5 features, not all of which Internet Explorer 9 supports. One such example is [ProgressEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866264/is-there-ajax-progress-event-in-ie-and-how-to-use-it).

Comment: I'll update this question if I can find any additional information for you.

Comment: The core issue is that although IE support for HTML5 has been improving there are a variety of outstanding issues in IE 9.